# Is 'I f*cked the dog' an actual idiom and are there alternatives

Tags: idioms, translation, offensive-language, idiom-requests, german

I am a non-native speaker from Germany. In German there's one idiom that goes:

> Sich die Eier schaukeln

Literally translated, this means "to rock the eggs", where "the eggs" are testicles. This is used to express severe boredom, especially to describe procrastinating or one's state of mind when you should be appointed to a task, but aren't.

It is somewhat vulgar as it involves testicles, yet it is a widely used idiom which would not actually be perceived as an inappropriate thing to say in general.

I searched for a translation that would fit and found:

> [fucked the dog](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fucked%20the%20dog)

(from Urban Dictionary). Now I would like to know if this is actually a common thing to say and whether there are any alternatives that are more suitable for daily use.

Comment: *screwed the pooch* is the idiom in AmE.  But it means to bungle something.

Comment: I have never heard _fuck the dog_ (or indeed _screw the pooch_) to describe hanging around, procrastinating, doing nothing when you ought to be doing something else. So at least in my personal experience, it’s definitely not common. _Sich die Eier schaukeln_ seems quite similar to **twiddling one’s thumbs**, though I’m not sure if the implication is quite the same—procrastination is not usually an inherent factor in twiddling one’s thumbs.

Comment: *We're treading water....* can mean we're hanging around waiting for something to do, or waiting for something to take place or for some decision to be made before we can get to work ourselves.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, a direct translation could work in some cases: [**scratching your balls**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=scratchball) tends to imply at least boredom, if not exactly procrastination, and definitely carries the same connotations as the German phrase.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet now that you mention it, we have another idiom, `Däumchen drehen`, which literally translates to 'twiddling one's thumbs'. Haven't thought of that!

Comment: "Contemplating one's navel" is an idiom with a similar meaning...in other words, killing time, being idle.

Comment: When Google translates this, it's *to rock the eggs*. I'd interpret that as *jerking-off*, *scratching my balls*, or *dicking around*. [Proz.com](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_german/idioms_maxims_sayings/2123693-to_fuck_the_dog.html) agrees.

Comment: *Fucking the dog* meaning *wasting time* is at the very least a current Canadian idiom. If you used it to mean *bungled the job* here, you'd be sorely misunderstood.

Comment: I added a literal translation of the phrase. If you there's a synonym or something that should be used instead, please correct me.

Comment: "which would not actually be perceived as an inappropriate thing to say in general" - maybe that is a regional thing, but as a native German speaker from South-Western Germany, I can hardly think of any situation where this would be an appropriate thing to say. I would normally perceive it as extremely vulgar and certainly rude when used to describe someone else's idling. **You should be *very* careful when using this idiom.**

Comment: @O.R.Mapper careful of what exactly? I'm from SW Germany as well; maybe it's the generational divide? In my experience, older people tend to lose their shit over the mentioning of genitalia rather than young folks. Anyways, I hear that pretty regulary

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Hm, possible. I was born after 1980 and I find it pretty rude to say about someone they "schaukeln sich die Eier". Therefore, I'd have said careful so as to not offend someone, or come across as generally rude, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'm sure I've read *I'm just fucking the dog until someone comes up with something for me to do* somewhere, and I seem to recall that book having a lot of phrases I thought were British English, it could have easily been Canadian, but I can't remember the book for the life of me.  So, can confirm @bye 's assertion that it does mean what you think it means in at least part of the world.

Comment: I'll third @bye in saying that the "wasting time" interpretation is definitely a common idiom in Canada.  It is also used in Quebecois French : *fourrer l'chien*.  http://oreilletendue.com/2012/04/30/du-chien-et-de-ses-usages-au-quebec/

Comment: In AmE, the phrase is not common and is not a set phrase. It means what it says literally. Probably not a good thing to use unless you're writing a police report.

Comment: From google research (questionable) I've found that others than Urban Dictionary corroborate the use of 'f**k the dog' as 'to waste time'. I've never heard it so it is probably not common, and 'f*ck' is much more vulgar in English than 'Eier' is in German. So if you would informally use with a coworker the 'Eier' sentence, you most likely wouldn't the 'dog' sentence in English. Among close friends maybe.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"Fuck the dog" (or its milder variant, "screw the pooch") comes from an old joke.

> There are various versions, but a drunk man ends up shooting the wife and screwing the pooch (instead of the other way around).

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/2hwl6b/where_did_shit_the_bed_and_screwed_the_pooch_come/)

It is certainly not about idleness, but epic failure to get a sequence right. Janus Bahs Jacquet's suggestion of using the literal translation of your German idiom is probably a lot closer to the mark for what you need. If you want something a little more sanitized, try "scratching our backsides*" (or use another body part to replace "balls").

*originally I had "heads" here, but Janus points out that that strays into a different meaning.

Comment: Most etymologies claiming that idioms come from jokes are spurious, but this one really sounds plausible. Do you have any better evidence for it?

Comment: @PeterShor: Evidence is all over the Web, but I can tell you that I personally heard this particular joke many times growing up, well before there was an Internet. So when I first heard the abstracted phrase "screw the pooch" there was no doubt where it came from.

Comment: Incidentally, I chose the Reddit example because it summed up the joke more succinctly than the other links I examined. (And I was too lazy to offer my own synopsis.)

Comment: Substituting the balls for the head doesn’t seem like the best option—scratching your head has quite a different meaning (puzzlement, bewilderment). You might say _scratching our back sides_, which I’d say is perhaps more euphemised than sanitised, but should still be usable.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I agree. My use of *heads* was to lead the OP away from vulgarity, but I take your point that it strays into a different idiom.

Comment: I do believe I’ve heard _scratching your elbow_ used more or less equivalently to _twiddling your thumbs_. That could work.

Comment: Never heard *scratching your elbow* except to mean the literal act of relieving an itch.

Comment: I've never heard *fuck the dog* in any context.  *Screw the pooch* is widely used, though (and I didn't know it came from a dirty joke :P).

Comment: @PeterCordes: *fuck the dog* is the more vulgar way of rendering the joke and the idiom. I first heard it that way because, well, when you're 12 or 13 years old you are trying out words for their shock value. :)

Comment: Another variant, which is the one I think I've heard the most (in the mountain west US) is "pork the pooch". I also think it's the more satisfying one to say. Must be all those p's. It's used when you or someone has an epic fail... "I really porked the pooch that time!"

Comment: Agreeing with @PeterCordes that I've never heard "fuck the dog" in any context. Adding that I'm an American.

Comment: You must travel in more genteel circles than I do. ^_^

Comment: I have heard the more alliterative "dicking the dog" applied to workers who were not working.

Comment: "Picking your belly button" is somewhat close, and probably carries a similar connotation that there is something more important that you should be doing.

Comment: "And what's that called?" ... "The aristocrats!"

Answer (score 32):

If you want an idiom that's still mildly vulgar, but still gets used in daily speech:

"We are just sitting here with our thumbs in our asses, (waiting for something to do)"

Comment: On ELL one would be asked *Does that mean each person has both thumbs up the ass, or is it one thumb per ass per person, or some mixture thereof?*

Comment: @TimRomano My favorite version of it is, you have one thumb in your ass and one in your mouth, and then play "switch".  (*n.b. this is my favorite version of the saying. **not** my favorite idle pastime.*)

Comment: An even less vulgar version is "thumbs up our butts."

Comment: @Hellion: I'm glad you clarified :)

Comment: +1, this is pretty close to the original phrase, but I would expect "thumbs *up* our asses". Same thing.

Comment: @TimRomano It's not actually stating whether the thumbs are in their owner's asses or in the asses of others in the same group...

Comment: None of these are mild enough to risk offending others, and care should be taken in professional environments lest one experience negative repercussion from careless usage.

Comment: @TimRomano I know you're just making a joke, but I'll clarify anyway. Talking about a specific person, it would be "*He's just sitting there with his thumb up his ass.*" - so expanding that to a group *should* mean that each individual person has one of their thumbs up their own ass.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Or possibly that each of them has one of their thumbs up their right-side neighbour’s ass, potentially. Depends on what kind of group we’re talking about. :-þ

Comment: Is this valid for both american and british english?

Comment: @beppe9000 Yes. At the very least, both audiences should at the least be able to infer the meaning.

Answer (score 19):

If you wanted to capture the spirit of the German, you could say

**We're just sitting here playing with ourselves while upper management is deciding which approach to take.**

or

**I'm not doing much of anything, just sitting here playing with myself.**

In a workplace context, it would not be taken literally.  :)

P.S. It's not the sort of thing men would typically say in mixed company at the office, however. Though I imagine that it could be said, given the right personalities.  You might hear female military personnel saying this, for example, "co-opting" male lingo.

Comment: Depends on the office. At one of my jobs, it would be perfectly commonplace for both men _and_ women to say this—including its more vulgar varieties. ;-)

Comment: In many US offices, one could get reprimanded or fired for using language like this  in mixed company.  We're very PC here, and our HR departments are havens for the humorless.

Answer (score 17):

The commonest expression I can think of to express boredom is "to twiddle one's thumbs".  "Screwing the pooch", while an idiom, has an entirely different meaning: to spectacularly mess up, usually in an embarrasingly public way.

Comment: I'm surprised this is so far down, it seems like the best match.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know how commonplace it is, but the phrase *jerking around* is what I would use in this situation:

**"Quit jerking around and do something productive!"**

Comment: I always thought that jerking around would involve stupid jokes and/or childish behaviour?

Comment: @Sprottenwels:  You may be correct.  Perhaps it doesn't apply as accurately as I thought.

Comment: +1, I'm familiar with this usage, and similar ones such as "quit screwing around", "quit fucking around".

Comment: In my experience "jerking around" is incorrect, it would be "jerking off". To be "jerked around" means to be forced by another to go through meaningless steps (that on the surface have the appearance of legitimacy or effectiveness) with the purpose of delaying or blocking one's own aims.

Comment: @ErikE "To be jerked around" and "to jerk around" are different, though.  The latter is the same as "to jerk off" in the sense of messing around.  [Lots of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quit+jerking+around%22).

Comment: @MatthewRead Okay, I concede that people use it, but it doesn't make sense. It just makes me think "jerking *what* around?" And *around* isn't a very good preposition for the action being suggested. It seems to me an ignorant portmanteau or malapropism combining "jerking off" and "screwing around."

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something non-vulgar that conveys the same meaning, try

> **"Loafing around"**

or

> **"Goofing off"**

Other more specific phrases might be **"Holding up the wall"** or **"Keeping the bench warm"**.

Comment: "Keeping the bench warm" and the similar "riding the pine" carry the implication that the idleness is involuntary and due to a perceived lack of ability.

Comment: That's why I said they were more specific - without knowing the context this needs to be used in, it's hard to say what would be most appropriate.  Anyhow, just pointing out that there's any number of non-vulgar alternatives to this phrase depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The past tense does not sound right to me, but a version of this term was actually used in Canada ca. 1980 and I'm fairly sure it would be understood today.

Q: "What are you up to?"

A: "Just f*cking the dog."

The meaning was that the person was idle or engaged in pointless or useless activities.

Source: personal experience

Comment: I don't know how things go in Canada, but I'm pretty sure this wouldn't translate the way you're thinking it would in the U.S..

Comment: @Iszi Obviously, I'm aware of the shocking literal interpretation. Personally, I wouldn't use it in Canada, let alone a foreign country in which the natives communicate in a range of different dialects, but the comment above by @ bye confirms my memory.

Comment: I'll agree with this.  In my experience the expression would be well understood as such in many parts of Canada.  It seems more common in rural areas and among somewhat older speakers.  There may also be an East/West bias (possibly more common in Eastern Canada).

Comment: As a Canadian living in Ontario I've never heard this expression.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I mentioned it to a fairly recent South African immigrant, and he said he's heard it more than once from older native-born Canadians.

Comment: I have come across the expression 'to fuck the dog' meaning to sit around (doing nothing at all) in a few North American criminal dramas, TV shows to be more axact, 'The Wire" in particular, the names of others I just can't recollect.

Comment: As an Australian I have never heard this expression, and if I did I would think it was meant literally. :)

Comment: @Iszi I've heard this in the US, and when SPOKEN, it is immediately obvious what they mean. If they were to text it though.... that may cause concern in the other party.